# How can I block all incoming and outgoing traffic in Windows 7 except Teamviewer?

Tags: windows-7, blocking, windows-firewall, traffic

I'm trying to figure how I can block all incoming and outgoing traffic except Teamviewer?
I've been trying to achieve this with the Windows 7 firewall but with no success.

Anybody any ideas?

Comment: Within the Windows Firewall (basing myself from XP) disable all exceptions except Teamviewer. You could use another firewall...

Comment: Thanks for your respones. What iv'e tried so far is something i found on another forum. Deleting all inbound and outbound rules and created new inbound and outbound rules for teamviewer.

Comment: I've tried something else. I blocked all the ports in my router to the computers ip adress except port 5938. Is this sufficient protection against possible virusses/trojans trying to " phone home"?

Comment: never know for sure unless you disconnect it from the internet permanently.

Comment: Using a router to block all ports, limits vulnerability from external networks, but it doesn't do squat for local protection. If you have a virus or other malware running on your local network, your computer that you're trying to protect still has its doors wide open. For full security, you should remove all access rules in the firewall, and create a new rule for teamviewer.
You may also leave a backdoor for yourself in case teamviewer locks up... like remote administration or so. It's always a wise thing to do if you don't have easy access to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Which ports are used by TeamViewer?** In general, TeamViewer will always
>   work if surfing on the Internet is possible. Hence, no firewall
>   configuration is required. As an alternative to port 80 HTTP, port 443
>   HTTPs is also being checked. In addition, it is also possible to open
>   only port 5938 TCP on the outgoing side. Data traffic should then be
>   able to pass through on this port without any problems.

[Source...](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your respones. What iv'e tried so far is something i found on another forum. Deleting all inbound and outbound rules and created new inbound and outbound rules for teamviewer.

Comment: If it worked you should try and write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get mine to work, I basically allow TCP port 5938, and allow Port 53 for DNS resolution. Once these 2 are activated, the Teamviewer works wonderfully!

I did it on a Sonicwall Firewall, and it worked!