# How do I block all internet access on the remote machine except for Teamviewer?

Tags: internet, remote, blocking, teamviewer

I would like to block all internet access on the remote machine but I still want to connect to it via Teamviewer.

Is there a way to do this? I've read: [How can I block all incoming and outgoing traffic in Windows 7 except Teamviewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/636203/how-can-i-block-all-incoming-and-outgoing-traffic-in-windows-7-except-teamviewer) but I'm unsure how it was done exactly. I'm on Windows 8.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: It will depend on what firewall you are using, but it should be easy to find the default settings, which you set to block all. Then find the program settings and set allow all for TeamViewer only, unless you want things like auto-updating to go through as well.

Comment: Do you recommend any firewall where it'll be easy to set this up and toggle on/off? Windows Firewall can get a bit tedious.

Comment: Not really. I've had problems with both McAfee and Norton in the past, and now find Kaspersky best suits my needs, but I cannot make any general recommendations. Nor can I assess how difficult you would find any of them to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I block all incoming and outgoing traffic in Windows 7 except Teamviewer?](http://superuser.com/questions/636203/how-can-i-block-all-incoming-and-outgoing-traffic-in-windows-7-except-teamviewer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no tools that were useful to me. So in the end, I did it the old fashion way: I got a real human being who had physical access to the remote machine to help out.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get mine to work, I basically allow TCP port 5938, and allow Port 53 for DNS resolution. Once these 2 are activated, the Teamviewer works wonderfully!